# Is it alright to connect with an interviewer on Linkedin?

Tags: interviewing, linkedin

I recently rejected the opportunity to move on to the final rounds of interviews with Company X. The reason why I rejected the opportunity was because I had accepted a job offer at Company Y. After assessing my risks and opportunities, I felt like I couldn't wait for Company X to come back with the possibility of a job offer. And besides, Company Y was too good an opportunity to say no to.

I enjoyed the interview process with Company X, and I'd like to connect on Linkedin with the two interviewers, A & B, whom I spoke with. Last week, I informed the HR recruiter, C, from Company X that I'd like to withdraw my application and would like to be considered for a role in future (though I have not heard an official reply from C). Is it alright to connect with A, B and C?

Answer (score 2):

I'd hedge my bets on this one.

Some people on LinkedIn like to have as many connections as humanly possible.  Some people prefer a tighter grip on their connections and only connect with people that they feel adds value.

People who conduct interviews get many LinkedIn invitations from recruiters and a lot of interviewee sharing the same idea as you.

What are you hoping to get out of this connection?  Are you expecting this guy to message you when another job comes up?  Will he be scanning your LinkedIn profile in the hope that you're available again? Does he regularly log in to LinkedIn to check his feed?

There's no harm in trying to reach out this way, but don't be surprised if your invitation is ignored or you don't hear anything, especially after you quit the interview process with them when they didn't respond fast enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

Connect with *everybody*. All of them has only a minor chance to have ever a new contact with them, but if you have a lot of similar contacts, their comulative chance is already significant.

No one has a word who are you contacting in a professional context on a professional *social networking* site.

In most cases, I contact *everybody* with them I had a job or interview relation. Sometimes they refuse, sometimes they don't. And, what's then? If they won't contact you, then they will simply refuse or ignore you. Others won't.

I also experienced an unintended side-effect of this strategy. Having a *lot* contacts, it makes me somehow more reputated in the eyes of the newer ones - despite that I don't allow anybody to see my friend list (if it can be set up).

This thing (reject contact list access) is also very important, because many of the "HR consultants" are actually data-fishing scripts. You have to protect your real, living contacts from them. Another significant part of them is a real human, but their intelligence and communication behavior is on the same level. You have to protect your contacts also from them.

So:

- contact everybody.
- don't allow *any* access to *everybody* for *anything*, except to yourself.
- periodically do something on your profile. It doesn't really matter, what, the only goal with it to get into their "news" or "recent changes" or any similar page, again and again.

Comment: If you are connected to your current manager, and start connecting with a bunch of recruiters, its not going to look good to your current employer.

Comment: @MisterSortofPositive Thanks, it is important! However, I had already a highly above-average contact network far before I joined my current company. I think I committed this mistake. But I don't believe that such cold-callers would have any useful offer for me, which would be so much better as my current job, that it would deserve a shift. I actually "reserve" them for the case, if I would need a new job. But the last what I want from them, that they bombard me with their *current* proposals (whose 95% is completely crap, 5% is not better as my current job).